# Elasticsearch installation failed on windows

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to install Elasticsearch 7.16.2 on windows server but while installation I am getting below error.

Installing service      :  "elasticsearch-service-x64"
Using ES_JAVA_HOME (64-bit):  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1"
-Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60;-Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10;-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch;-Xss1m;-Djava.awt.headless=true;-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8;-Djna.nosys=true;-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow;-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages;-Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true;-Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true;-Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0;-Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0;-Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false;-Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true;-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true;-Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT;--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED;-XX:+UseG1GC;-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\jioapp\AppData\Local\Temp\2\elasticsearch;-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError;-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError;-XX:HeapDumpPath=data;-XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log;-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m;-Xms31744m;-Xmx31744m;-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=16642998272;-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30;-XX:G1ReservePercent=25
Failed installing 'elasticsearch-service-x64' service

Thanks,
Shashikant

Answer (score 1):

Whoever has the same problem, try 'elasticsearch-service.bat remove'. I actually had the same error, checked the log files and it said that the service already existed and that's why it was failing to install. Once I removed it I was able to reinstall it and then I had issues starting it but I think it was because of some typos in the elasticsearch.yml file.

If that doesn't work, maybe try 'elasticsearch-service.bat manager' for some information and check your environment variables.

Comment: I found solution for this issue. This issue was occurred due to compatibility issue with JDK